# O que preciso para programar em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compilação, ide

Uso o Delphi e preciso de algo parecido para programar um código como [esse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797870/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-listt-requires-1-type-ar). O que tenho que obter para começar pro gramar em C#?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Community.

Comment: Você não precisa fazer isto agora ou se não achar que deve mas se a resposta lhe atendeu bem você pode aceitá-la como correto. E quando tiver pontos suficientes, poderá votar em todos os posts do site. Veja o [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Como você já deve ter percebido esta linguagem é o [C#](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))). Ela depende de uma plataforma chamada [.NET](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_.NET) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)) que tem uma grande chance de já estar instalada no seu computador. Ou seja, para programar em C# você não precisa mais nada além do que você já tem , embora eu recomende pegar coisas mais modernas e sofisticadas.

Provavelmente você vai querer um IDE que ajude programar. O IDE oficial do C# criado pela Microsoft é o [Visual Studio](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)) e existe uma versão totalmente gratuita chamada [Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx). Você pode baixar, instalar e usar sem preocupações.

Claro que esta é a parte fácil. Aprender usar a linguagem, a plataforma toda, entender o que está fazendo é um pouco mais complicado que isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: valeu cara... mas tem algum jeito de converter esse codigo pra delphi ou tenho q instalar esse programa ai mesmo ?

Comment: Exatamente este código não mas dá para fazer algo muito parecido. Este código é relativamente básico, se você conhecendo Delphi não consegue escrever algo tão básico, acho que o código não terá muita utilidade.

Comment: cara eu sei o basico... mas é meio diferente os uses vc manja de delphi mano tem algum jeito de vc converter pra mim ?

Comment: @Matrix Sugiro você postar uma pergunta separada aqui no site, perguntando como criar uma lista de números aleatórios em Delphi (é isso que você quer?)